# How to change locale in momentJS?

Tags: react-native, momentjs

This is what I have but it does not work.

```
import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/min/moment-with-locales'
import 'moment-duration-format' // used by moment

componentDidMount () {
  console.log(moment.locale())
  console.log(moment.locale('zh-cn')) 
  console.log(moment.locale()) 
}
```

console log outputs:
en, en, en

expected console log output: en, zh-cn, zh-cn

When I tried changing import moment from 'moment' to import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales' but it throws an error on this line:

```
const total = moment.duration(this.props.stoveUsage.total, 'seconds').format('H:mm', { trim: false })
```

error: momentWithLocales2.default.duration(...).format is not a function

Comment: I'm not sure that `import 'moment/min/moment-with-locales'` is a valid way to import locales, maybe you can try replacing it with `import 'moment/locale/zh-cn` as showed [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need to do is to import the locale you want to use. In my example, I wanted to make sure all the dates were in Spanish and this is what I did:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
```

Then whenever you need it just do:

```
moment.locale('es')
moment(date).format("DD - MMMM - YYYY"
```

The output will be:

```
19 - julio - 2018
```

I guess you will have to import as many locales as you need in your application.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to Nicoyuste's answer, you can import it dynamically with

```
import(`moment/locale/${navigator.language.toLocaleLowerCase()}`).then();
```

Comment: What is navigator?

Comment: The Navigator interface represents the state and the identity of the user agent. It allows scripts to query it and to register themselves to carry on some activities.