# moment.js change locale not working

Tags: momentjs

My project is a react project.

My website is a mutilanguage website, when I change the web language. `moment.locale(lang)` not working.

My code is:

```js
const startDate = moment.utc(start).locale(lang);
const endDate = moment.utc(end).locale(lang);
```

whatever I set `lang` I check the `startDate.locale()` always is `'en'`
`startDate.format('ll')` result always is English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I change the language of moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js)

Comment: same issue here did you got the fix yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change locale in momentJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530110/how-to-change-locale-in-momentjs)

Answer (score 74):

If the project was created using create-react-app, moment locales were probably [excluded by default](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2187/files).

This is now documented in the ["Moment.js locales are missing" section](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#momentjs-locales-are-missing) of create-react-app's troubleshooting guide.

Solution: explicitly import locales in addition to 'moment':

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';
import 'moment/locale/es';
// etc. as required
```

Comment: I had to add "/dist" to the import: import 'moment/dist/locale/es'

Comment: @HectorToro you helped me thanks

Answer (score 29):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2962), from 2022 on or so, it has to be imported like so:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/dist/locale/de';

moment.locale('de');
```

if this doesn't work, try this change:

```
import moment from 'moment/dist/moment';
```

Comment: thanks, i used `import 'moment/locale/fr'`; or `import 'moment/lib/locale/fr';` but not working `import 'moment/dist/locale/fr';` work

Comment: Bloody christ thanks for this. Nothing worked, this did.

Answer (score 2):

For a react native app importing moment like this fixed the issue

```
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
```

[reference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/)

Comment: I was looking for the exact solution for my React project, your suggestion worked great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you do

```
import 'moment/min/locales'
```

Instead of individual import of each locale.
In my case it resolve my problem

Comment: Got them to bundle for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334751/8318855

You should use the `moment.updateLocale` function

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs 18.2.0
Moment 2.30.1

```
import moment from "moment";
import 'moment/locale/ru';

let now = moment();
console.log(now.format('LLLL'));
```